# Erro ao utilizar recursos de um Servlet

Tags: java, aplicação-web, jsp, tomcat, servlet

Boa noite colegas,

Por favor, preciso da ajuda para entender o que esta acontecendo de errado,

Tenho o seguinte form:

```
form action="CronogramaNegocio" method="get">

                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                    <label>DEPARTAMENTO</label>
                    <select class="form-control" required name="departamento" >
                        <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
                        <option value="QUALIDADE">QUALIDADE</option>
                        <option>LIVROS FISCAIS</option>
                        <option>-</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                       <label>DATA</label>
                       <input type="date" class="form-control" name="hData"/>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                        <label>Hora Inicial</label>
                        <input type="time" class="form-control" name="hInicio"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                    <label>Hora Final</label>
                    <input type="time" class="form-control" name="hFim"/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                    <label>TIPO AUDITORIA</label>
                    <select class="form-control" required name="tipoAuditoria" >
                        <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
                        <option value="1ªPARTE">1ª PARTE-</option>
                        <option>2ª PARTE</option>
                        <option>3ª PARTE</option>
                    </select>
                </div>




      <p style="float:right;">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-verde" value="Salvar" onclick="salvar()" />
        </p>
            </form>
```

Como podem ver ele chama um Servlet chamado CronogramaNegocio

A passagem de parâmetros creio que esteja correta já que o resultado é:

```
http://localhost:8080/Qualidade/CronogramaNegocio?departamento=LIVROS+FISCAIS&hData=2018-11-06&hInicio=21%3A01&hFim=01%3A01&tipoAuditoria=1�PARTE&frm_length=10
```

Dentro do Servlet eu realizo operações para gravar no banco de dados os dados:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.CronogramaAuditoria;
import model.DAO.CronogramaAuditoriaDAO;

/**
 *
 * @author Rafael H. Aguiar
 */
public class CronogramaNegocio extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
                      System.out.print("Entrou no metodo de salvar Cronograma");

            String tipoAuditoria = request.getParameter("tipoAuditoria");
            String data = request.getParameter("data");
            String departamento = request.getParameter("departamento");
            String hInicio = request.getParameter("hInicio");
            String hFim = request.getParameter("hFim");


            CronogramaAuditoriaDAO croDAO = new CronogramaAuditoriaDAO();




                CronogramaAuditoria cro = new CronogramaAuditoria(tipoAuditoria, data, hInicio, hFim, departamento);
                croDAO.create(cro);
                        System.out.print("Registro salvo com sucesso");



        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Porém esta sendo apresentado o seguinte erro:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Qualidade/CronogramaNegocio
type Status report

message /Qualidade/CronogramaNegocio

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
```

Alguém saberia por gentileza me dizer o porque disso?

Comment: como está o seu arquivo web.xml?

Comment: Resolvi, o problema estava sendo erro do netBeans na construções do projeto, limpei ele e deu certo.